# How many concrete piers do I need to support a tiny house (12x28 and 20feet high)

Tags: concrete, foundation, support, engineered-flooring, architecture

I need help, I am building a tiny house, I am not sure how many concrete piers do I need for a 12x28 tiny house and that will be max of 20 ft high

thank you!

Comment: Minimum 4 - one on each corner. 6 (one on each corner, one in the middle of each long side) might make a lot of sense. But **impossible to tell without more details** - what kind of soil or base? Where? (some places get much more complicated due to concerns about earthquakes or hurricanes) How high off the ground? What kind of materials (concrete block may be quite different from a plywood shell)? etc.

Comment: As noted. Not enough information to provide an answer. Please use the **edit button** to add ALL the pertinent info.

Comment: Will local codes permit such a small building?  Often people have to put tiny homes on trailer wheels to evade zoning.

Comment: The one my son has just built has 6, also on a slope and the area is known for seismic activity - taken as part of the planning process.

Comment: It depends entirely on your floor system design. How far are the beams rated to span?

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of the piers and their anchor depth and the fact that you can use metal (ibeam) cross beams, you can definitely do just 4.    Remember when building on piers, more is not better (unless we are talking large commercial building).   When you add more piers you are allowing for a greater future issues with leveling based on heave.

Now that was just the "minimum".

In real world home building you would probably have three piers on the long side - so 6.

Comment: Of course, this implies a floor system designed to span ~28 feet. That takes some robust beams.